# Finite abelian group in the form $G \cong C_{m_1} \times C_{m_2} \times \dots \times C_{m_\ell}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

We are given that $G = C_{18} \times C_{75}$ and asked to find $G$ in the form $C_{m_1} \times C_{m_2} \times \dots \times C_{m_\ell}$ where $m_i | m_{i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq \ell-1$.
I have found a couple of solutions to this but I'm wondering if they are both right.
1: \begin{array}{cc}
 & 2\\
3 & 9 \\
 & 25 \\
\hline
3&450
\end{array}
Which would give $G=C_3 \times C_{450}$

2:\begin{array}{ccc}
 & &2\\
3 & 3&3 \\
 & 5&5 \\
\hline
3&15&30
\end{array}
Which gives $G=C_3 \times C_{15} \times C_{30}$
Are both these correct? Or neither? Why?
Apologies if this is a repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a unique answer to this type of question.
So both of your answers can't be correct.
But one of your answers is correct.
Note that a cyclic group of order $p^n$ for $p$ a prime is never the direct product of smaller subgroups.