# Find all abelian groups of order 60

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find all abelian groups of order 60

$\mathbb{Z}_{60} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5$

$\mathbb{Z}_{30}\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong  (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

$\mathbb{Z}_{15}\times \mathbb{Z}_4 \cong  (\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5)\times  \mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$

Is it right?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "real analysis"? This is abstract algebra, not analysis.

Comment: Aren't the right hand sides of the first and last ones the same?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups can be used here. See, for example, Joseph Gallian's textbook *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* or another undergraduate abstract algebra text.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups says that Every finite abelian group is the direct sum of cyclic groups, each of prime power order.

The prime factors of 60 are $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ and we can write 60 as the product of primes in the following ways:

$2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$

$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$

Therefore every abelian group of order 60 must be isomorphic to one of the groups

$\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: There is another canonical way to write the groups. They are all possible direct products of cyclic groups of increasing orders $m_1, m_2, ...$ such that $m_1|m_2|m_3...$. In this case the two results would be $C_{60}$ and $C_2 \times C_{30}$ respectively.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2541773/465208